Prometheus join use all values from left and only use right for filtering
I am trying to do a query with a "join" between two metrics, the right-hand metric is just there to filter on a field that is not in the metric I actually want.  I have finally gotten it to the point where it returns the correct filtered instances, but it is using the value from the wrong side.
  100
-
    avg by (instance) (windows_cpu_time_total{instance=~"$vm",mode="idle"}) * 100
  * on (instance) group_right ()
    max by (instance) (
      label_replace(
        windows_hyperv_vm_cpu_total_run_time{core="0",instance=~"$host"},
        "instance",
        "$1",
        "vm",
        "(.*)"
      )
    )

How can I use the right side only for filtering. Something similar to an inner join or "in" statement?
